# Center Button Option in JOptionPane Modal

Tags: java, joptionpane

I am wondering if there is anyway to center my "Overwrite" option/button within the JOptionPane call.
Currently, the button automatically styles to the right side of the modal like so:

[image]

The code:

```
public String clearScansWarningModal() {
    Object[] options = {"Overwrite"};
    
    int selectedOption= JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "You are attempting to open a scan file on top of an already existing one.\n"
            +"Choosing Overwrite will clear the workspace before opening the new file.\n",              
            "Warning!",
            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE,
            2, 
            null,
            options,  
            options[0]); 
    
    LOGGER.info("User selected " + options[selectedOption]);
    return (String)options[selectedOption];
}
```

If not within the JOptionPane call, what would likely be the next best solution? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `JOptionPane` itself won't allow you to do that, for that kind of functionality, you'd have to roll your own dialog

Comment: UX note:  It is a good idea to allow the user to back out of a destructive operation, usually with a “Cancel” button.  The warning doesn’t do much good otherwise.